# Кэширование файлов на хостинге

Tags: php, hosting

Добавил новые файлы на хостинг(фотографии + поменял адресата отправки формы), но фотографии до сих пор остались старыми, а форма отправляется на старый адрес. Может оно как-то кэшируется (Макхост), или через сколько времени изменения вступят в силу? Спасибо.

Comment: Всё кэшируется в браузерах у пользователей (в том числе у вас), чистите браузерный кэш

Comment: Надо разобраться с настройками хостинга. Можно ли у него регулировать время кеша статических файлов. Если там apache, то можно и через htaccess добавить правила

Comment: Ну или переработать свой код, чтобы к адресам статики добавлялась "соль". типа script.js?v=123456789